# How can I keep randomized UNIX timestamp in specific hour range in SQL?

Tags: sql, unix, mariadb, timestamp

What I'm attempting to do: within SQL, I'm trying to assign a randomized UNIX timestamp within specific range of hours of the last 24h.

What I got so far is this:

**Step 1** with "0" placeholder - making sure the hour of unix timestamp is changed only for those whose random hour wasn't assigned this day.

```sql
UPDATE users SET random_hour = 0 WHERE random_hour > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 86400);
```

**Step 2:**
Made the query actually generate a random timestamp within last 24h.

```sql
UPDATE users SET random_hour = UNIX_TIMESTAMP((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 24 * 60 * 60) SECOND)) WHERE random_hour > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 86400);
```

**Step 3:**
Make sure the hours assigned are between 8:00-16:00 GMT.

This is where I'm failing.

**Limitations I'm facing are:**

- it has to be unix timestamp (other columns and scripts depend on all times being in unix timestamps)
- this is a task that runs frequently and assigns users the random hour, that's why there's a check for `random_hour > current_timestamp() - 86400`, so that it's stable, and that's also why I can't just work on the current day's timestamp range to do it,
- database i'm running is MariaDB 10

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh edited, final line was cut when i was pasting the question from Notepad, thx!

Comment: A dbms tag is extra important when it comes to date/time, because most products have their own functions.

Comment: "within last 24h" -- Is that from the current "second"?  The start of the current hour?  "Yesterday"?